# How does __rust_begin_short_backtrace work in Rust?

Tags: rust

As titled.

I know that `__rust_begin_short_backtrace` is used for stack backtracing, but how does it work actually? I find the implementation of it is really short just like below. And what it does is only calling the passed-in function indirectly, and return back the result. I also find the counterpart function `__rust_end_short_backtrace` which has totally identical implementation. The code is at ***library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs***.

```
/// Fixed frame used to clean the backtrace with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`. Note that
/// this is only inline(never) when backtraces in libstd are enabled, otherwise
/// it's fine to optimize away.
#[cfg_attr(feature = "backtrace", inline(never))]
pub fn __rust_begin_short_backtrace<F, T>(f: F) -> T
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
{
    let result = f();

    // prevent this frame from being tail-call optimised away
    crate::hint::black_box(());

    result
}
```

Another part of the related implementation is also at "***library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs***". Below is a snippet of code of this part which I think is highly related and important, but I don't understand the logic here that how Rust deals with the symbols that relate to the previous two functions:

```
 backtrace_rs::trace_unsynchronized(|frame| {
    if print_fmt == PrintFmt::Short && idx > MAX_NB_FRAMES {
        return false;
    }

    let mut hit = false;
    let mut stop = false;
    backtrace_rs::resolve_frame_unsynchronized(frame, |symbol| {
        hit = true;
        if print_fmt == PrintFmt::Short {
            if let Some(sym) = symbol.name().and_then(|s| s.as_str()) {
                if sym.contains("__rust_begin_short_backtrace") {
                    stop = true;
                    return;
                }
                if sym.contains("__rust_end_short_backtrace") {
                    start = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        if start {
            res = bt_fmt.frame().symbol(frame, symbol);
        }
    });
    if stop {
        return false;
    }
    if !hit {
        if start {
            res = bt_fmt.frame().print_raw(frame.ip(), None, None, None);
        }
    }

    idx += 1;
    res.is_ok()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Rust is inserting these "dummy symbols" to allow a short backtrace.

Consider this code

```rs
fn a() {
    b()
}

fn b() {
    c()
}

fn c() {
    d()
}

fn d() {
    panic!()
}

fn main() {
    a()
}
```

This gives a nice backtrace

```
$ rustc demo.rs
$ RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./demo
thread 'main' panicked at 'explicit panic', demo.rs:14:5
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic
   1: demo::d
   2: demo::c
   3: demo::b
   4: demo::a
   5: demo::main
   6: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

If we instead use `RUST_BACKTRACE=full`

```
$ RUST_BACKTRACE=full ./demo
thread 'main' panicked at 'explicit panic', demo.rs:14:5
stack backtrace:
   0:        0x107e34fe4 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::ha70d3c0580051b5e
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:90:5
   1:        0x107e34fe4 - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h70c3b3ef22cddd13
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
   2:        0x107e34fe4 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::h698e42c1766250fa
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:67:5
   3:        0x107e34fe4 - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h18cc31b07c2f1a67
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:46:22
   4:        0x107e4808d - core::fmt::write::h24f8349e8e89c9af
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1096:17
   5:        0x107e33046 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::hc54d7d6e95b15753
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1568:15
   6:        0x107e36b79 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h07ca439149358748
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:49:5
   7:        0x107e36b79 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::hb7331bf9c4b208ca
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:36:9
   8:        0x107e36b79 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h11b550d560f5cc66
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/panicking.rs:208:50
   9:        0x107e36709 - std::panicking::default_hook::he168e99d1cf91c3c
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/panicking.rs:225:9
  10:        0x107e371fb - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hf87bfc4afef21ea6
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/panicking.rs:591:17
  11:        0x107e18d27 - std::panicking::begin_panic::{{closure}}::h631923d2be23e79e
  12:        0x107e18998 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::h891b6a0b6f9c1b80
  13:        0x107e4bcfb - std::panicking::begin_panic::hd2dfddb0fed650c0
  14:        0x107e18aec - demo::d::h9d9ff8ddd5377da5
  15:        0x107e18ac9 - demo::c::haceeec3fee4323ba
  16:        0x107e18ab9 - demo::b::h4146166847508fc7
  17:        0x107e18aa9 - demo::a::h60d47e17615f49c4
  18:        0x107e18af9 - demo::main::h60dea0663d4b849d
  19:        0x107e18bea - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::hf435db03deecd456
  20:        0x107e189cd - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h936624db758e7870
  21:        0x107e194d0 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::ha060b13a4d59d3f5
  22:        0x107e37574 - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once::h0e377e204feaadc3
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:259:13
  23:        0x107e37574 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h9c5b8eda90bbe0b7
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/panicking.rs:379:40
  24:        0x107e37574 - std::panicking::try::he150bdff9d5b30f2
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/panicking.rs:343:19
  25:        0x107e37574 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h04e9c415c0907892
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/panic.rs:431:14
  26:        0x107e37574 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::h86f505dc7de50d93
                               at /rustc/2fd73fabe469357a12c2c974c140f67e7cdd76d0/library/std/src/rt.rs:51:25
  27:        0x107e194a5 - std::rt::lang_start::h9d080ccd85b4c518
  28:        0x107e18b22 - _main
```

Which is the full stack trace. However is isn't very usefull as most of it is language internals. Therefor, in the normal mode, rust scans the stack for the `__rust_end_short_backtrace` and `__rust_begin_short_backtrace` functions.

These functions dont do anything (hence the trickery to stop them being optimized away), but are rust their for the backtracer to pick up.